# How to filter rows by length in Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm using a row filter to filter out columns that are longer than given length. Under filter conditions there are no conditions for checking row length.

So the workaround is to use:

```
Field1 REGEXP [^.{0,80}$]
OR
Field1 IS NULL

Field2 REGEXP [^.{0,120}$]
OR
Field2 IS NULL
```

Length check is a very common requirement. Is there a function/simpler way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Data Validator step:

Create a new validation for every column you want to check and set "Max string length" for every validation created.

You can redirect erroneous rows using "Error handling of step" hop:
[image]

By default these rows have same structure and values as the input rows, but you can also include additional information, such as the name of the erroneous column or error description.

Alternatively, you can compute a string length before filtering using calculator step, but it may create a lot of additional columns if you have multiple columns to check.

And, of course, you can always perform such checks in User Defined Java Class or Modified Java Script Value.

Comment: The data validator stops the transformation. How can I make it ignore those rows? Is there a output type that discards everything?

Comment: You are likely to need "Error handling of step" hop after the validator step in addition to "Main output of step" hop (I've added a screenshot as example).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about strings, you can use a Calculator step with the somewhat hard to find calculation "Return the length of a string A". That will give you the values for your Filter Rows step.

Comment: Not so hard to find, if you use the word `length` as a filter.  Took me way too long to notice this feature.